# exporting variable globally

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I can save the IP address of the current server to a variable and echo it out.

```
# myvar=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')

# echo $myvar
10.11.6.117
```

What I want to do is to "export" it as a global variable so that I can use it in shell scripts/ other commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then `export` it.

```
export varname="value"
```

This will be available afterwards (exported into the environment).

Alternative:

```
varname="value"
export $varname
```

If you want this globally for every shell upon login, you can put it into `/etc/profile` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the shell you are using:

- for *sh*-compatible shells (including *bash*) use: `VARIABLE=value; export VARIABLE` or just `export VARIABLE=value`
- for *tcsh*: `setenv VARIABLE value`
- for *zsh*: `export VARIABLE=value`

Answer (score 1):

For login shells you can set the variable globally in `/etc/profile`. Edit the file and add the following lines just after the `export PATH ...` line:

```
myvar=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
export myvar
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `source` it from other shell scripts:

```
source /path/to/ip.sh
echo $myvar
```

or:

```
. /path/to/ip.sh
echo $myvar
```